# Not returning all claims and policy authorization issue

Tags: c#, identityserver4, asp.net-core-2.0

I'm using IdentityServer4 hybrid flow sample app for testing and playing around with IS4: https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Samples/tree/release/Quickstarts/5_HybridFlowAuthenticationWithApiAccess

Config.cs in IS4 have two defined test users:

```
return new List<TestUser>
        {
            new TestUser
            {
                SubjectId = "1",
                Username = "alice",
                Password = "password",

                Claims = new List<Claim>
                {
                    new Claim("name", "Alice"),
                    new Claim("website", "https://alice.com")
                }
            },
            new TestUser
            {
                SubjectId = "2",
                Username = "bob",
                Password = "password",

                Claims = new List<Claim>
                {
                    new Claim("name", "Bob"),
                    new Claim("website", "https://bob.com")
                }
            }
        };
```

"Secure.cshtml" in MVC client should display Type and Value for all claims, but I'm seeing only

```
sid: ec1e3b0513f711ca6c29a90494aa9741
sub: 1
idp:local
name:Alice
```

with no "website" claim displayed. How can I get that claim back alongside with name?
options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint is set to "true". (MVC Client Startup.cs)

So, if I create a policy:

```
services.AddAuthorization(options => {
                options.AddPolicy("testPolicy", builder =>
                {
                    builder.RequireAuthenticatedUser();
                    builder.RequireClaim("website", "https://alice.com");
                });
            });
```

and protect "Secure" action with it:

```
[Authorize(Policy = "testPolicy")]
        public IActionResult Secure()
        {
            ViewData["Message"] = "Secure page.";

            return View();
        }
```

There is no way I can access it because "website" claim is not returned from user endpoint... Any ideas?
Note: I didn't make any changes on sample app except "testPolicy".

Answer (score 0):

As I remember you need to add `UserClaims` to your `ApiResource`:

```
    public static IEnumerable<ApiResource> GetApiResources()
    {
        return new List<ApiResource>
        {
            new ApiResource("api1.access")
            {
                UserClaims = new List<string>
                {
                    JwtClaimTypes.Name, // or just put "name"
                    JwtClaimTypes.WebSite // or just put "website" 
                },
                Scopes = new List<Scope>
                {
                    new Scope("api1.access")
                }
            }
        };
    }
```